# Python 3.5 with Django 1.8 Create super user?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.8

I have windows 8, python 3.5 and Django version 1.8.2

As suggested on Django documentation I tried to create super user using following code:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

When I enter the above command, it prompts me for username,
when I enter username it prompts me for email and when I enter email address  instead of prompting for password it shows following error.

```
G:\djangblog\mysite>python manage.py createsuperuser

Username (leave blank to use 'saphal'): admin

Email address: local@admin.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\software_installed\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__
init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\software_installed\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__
init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\software_installed\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\ba
se.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\software_installed\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\manag
ement\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 50, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "E:\software_installed\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\ba
se.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\software_installed\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\manag
ement\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 124, in handle
    password = getpass.getpass()
  File "E:\software_installed\python\lib\getpass.py", line 104, in win_getpass
    msvcrt.putwch(c)
AttributeError: module 'msvcrt' has no attribute 'putwch'
```

*I have installed python on E drive and have my work folder on G drive.

Comment: 3.5 ist not even released (and won't be for some more months). You might find some more errors. Why are you working with a pre-production version?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug in Python](https://bugs.python.org/issue23995) and was resolved.

You can either upgrade to the latest 3.5 version; or downgrade to 3.4.3 (the recommended version).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Sorry for late reply!!